# Using Wildfly 8, I'm able to HTTP GET the entire filesystem through any WAR deployed in the server

Tags: wildfly-8, undertow

I'm using WildFly 8.1.0.Final (JBoss) on a windows server and I've deployed a WAR ("test.war") with a single HTML file at its root.

Now, using CURL I can read any file on my filesystem:

```
curl http://localhost/test/..\\..\\..\\..\\..\\..\\..\\..\\..\\..\\Windows\\win.ini
```

Note that this also happens when accessing a remote host.
Also note that the number of "..\" probably depends on where is Wildfly deployed.

Obviously this is not desired...

So I tried to fix this by explicitly disabling directory-listing even though listing is disabled by default and my using "curl" doesn't browse any directory. This didn't help.

It feels like a bug in Undertow though I can't prove it.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.